# Inversion in the adverbial clause

Tags: inversion, negative-inversion

Two questions about this sentence

> Only now could he see what a terrible decision he had made.

The inversion should happen in the main clause and not in the adverbial clause, isn't it?

The combination of 'could' (past) and now (strict present) is very confusing. Is it common? Is it correct?

Answer (score 1):

This is a subject-auxiliary inversion and it occurs in the main clause. I don't see how it occurs in a subordinate clause. The inversion is triggered by the initial *Only*. If you remove it or place it at the end of the sentence, the inversion won't occur:

> He could see what a terrible decision he had made only now.

It is correct and common, and for most speakers, the inversion is obligatory when *Only* is in the initial position.

Comment: So, next sentence is also correct: "Only now he could see what a terrible decision had he made". Isn't it?

Comment: @cape The inversion is obligatory according to Huddleston & Pullum (2002). So the sentence is ungrammatical. I edited my answer.